# Getting "Newer Posts" and "Older Posts" links on a Specialized Page Template

Tags: wordpress

I am using a Specialized Page Template to display list of posts. I am using the following code for that:

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged
);
$all_posts = get_posts($args); 
?>

<?php foreach ( $all_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );  ?>
/* the loop */
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now I want to put "Newer Posts" and "Older Posts" links below it. `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` prints nothing here. How can I add these two links on this page?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
<?php next_posts_link( __( '&laquo; Older posts' ) ); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &raquo;' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Same issue. Passing arguments inside these functions does not make any difference. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

As from the codex

`next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` doesn't work in the custom page template as a static page

Refer [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link) for more details

**These functions does not work with static pages**

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate it using `WP_Query`, as it contains the `max_num_pages` attribute. If `$paged` is equal to 1, we don't print the `previous` link. If it is equal to `max_num_pages`, we don't print the `next` link.

The links are constructed based on `get_the_permalink()` that we grab before doing the loop. You have to adjust to your permalinks structure, check the code comments.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$this_page = get_permalink();
$previous = $paged - 1;
$next = $paged + 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $the_query->the_post(); 
        echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>'; 
    endwhile;

    if( $paged != 1 ) 
    {
        // DEFAULT PERMALINKS
        # echo "<a href='$this_page&paged=$previous'>previous</a>";
        // PRETTY PERMALINKS
        echo "<a href='{$this_page}page/$previous/'>previous</a>";
    }

    if( $paged != 1 && $paged != $the_query->max_num_pages ) 
    {   
        // SEPARATOR
        echo ' | ';
    }

    if( $paged != $the_query->max_num_pages ) 
    {
        // DEFAULT PERMALINKS
        # echo "<a href='$this_page&paged=$next'>next</a>";
        // PRETTY PERMALINKS
        echo "<a href='{$this_page}page/$next/'>next</a>";
    }

endif;
```

Found this article, [Next/Previous Post Navigation Outside of the WordPress Loop](http://digwp.com/2010/04/post-navigation-outside-loop/), although it didn't help, I'll leave here as reference.